# Get post categories with Wordpress JSON API (WP-API plugin)

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

Hoping this is an easy/fast one. I am using WP-API and I'd like to get the categories that a given post belongs to (I'd also like to get the tags).

From the docs the only way I can see to do this is to request the contents of each category and check whether or not the `post_id` is in one of them. Same story for tags since it also uses the taxonomy structure.

How can I ask a `GET /posts/:post_id` request to return categories and tags?

Answer (score 0):

`GET /posts` returns an array of posts, and each post has a "terms" child with a "category" array as its child.

Same goes for `GET /posts/:id`

If you assign tags to a post, my understanding is that it should return the tags inside the "terms" as well.

Comment: Thanks thomers, but neither of those are returned when I call `GET /posts`. I get back `id`, `title`, `content`, `status`, `type`, `author`, `parent`, `link`, `date`, `modified`, `format`, `slug`, `guid`, `excerpt`, `menu_order`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `sticky`, `date_gmt`, `modified_gmt`, and `featured_image`.

Comment: Which JSON API did you install specifically, and which version?

Comment: I installed WP-API develop branch, hash 612a6094adb023. https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/commit/612a6094adb02387f3d64a9ef50572810b57761c . It looks like just today a commit was made to include the taxonomy section by default: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/commit/164d771dc11d2061f7518ad2182f866f0cb336e0 EDIT: It doesn't look like that commits has changed the response I get from `GET /posts`